# TortoiseSVN - New files are marked as ignored rather than unversion

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am creating new files on my project but for some reason they are marked by TortoiseSVN as ignored by default rather than unversion, so I keep check changes in without new files then I have to go manually to the folder right clicking on the file to add it to finally check it in, this make the whole process really annoying.

Any idea?

Regards

Comment: `*.*` in global ignore pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you configured to ignore all new files unintentionally.
Click the right mouse button in the project folder and then select TortoiseSVN > Properties.
If there is a property "svn: global-ignores" with Value *"*"* or *"*.*"*, remove the property or edit it to remove the two mentioned values.

Answer (score -1):

These files are ignored due to (some) ignore-rules. You have to detect this rule, if you don't want to continue  adding files by hand